# How best to reflect State of an object affected by a Future in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this value of type **list** that I'll be using on a **ListViewBuilder**.

I have a condition that checks if the list has a length of 0 or more so that I can show an **Empty State** widget if there are no available items in the list and to show the ListViewBuilder if there are items in the list.

Running the logic actually show's that it works but my problem is that since the list object's length starts at 0 it always draws my "Empty State" widget first but then quickly draws the actual ListViewBuilder when my Future function finishes incrementing on my list. Though it works, the experience for the user to quickly see the "Empty State" even if there actually items on list is quite jarring.

Hoping you guys can help me on a way I can only show either state my list is on without having to pass through from the initial state of zero.

Below is a representation of what I am talking about, you can see that isolated my three states: NULL (White), ==0 (Blue), >=1 (Green).

[image]

```
What I'm trying to achieve is to just go to Green without showing Blue.
```

EDIT: ADDED SAMPLE CODE BELOW

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class MainProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<String> list = <String>[];

  MainProvider() {
    initList();
  }

  initList() async {
    // CODE BELOW IS TO SIMULATE MAKING DATABASE CALLS
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 800), () {
        addToList('String');
      });
    }
  }

  addToList(String string) {
    list.add(string);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

void main() => runApp(AppIndex());

class AppIndex extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: AppProvider(),
    );
  }
}

class AppProvider extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<MainProvider>(
      create: (context) => MainProvider(),
      child: AppContent(),
    );
  }
}

class AppContent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var mainProvider = Provider.of<MainProvider>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: mainProvider.list == null
          ? Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Center(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'NULL',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          : mainProvider.list.length == 0
              ? Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      mainProvider.list.length.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : mainProvider.list.length >= 0
                  ? Container(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          mainProvider.list.length.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  : Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          mainProvider.list.length.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
    );
  }
}
```

> In my code, I am using my Future function to call out database items
>   to add to my list. In the sample code above, I intentionally added a
>   delay to simulate database call times.

Comment: Share your code for better understanding

Comment: I'll update my question with sample code. Thanks

Comment: @AverageCoder what about if say you retrieve your list over the internet, and the connection takes 25 seconds to give you the first item? What are you gonna showing the user then? I mean, what you're showing here seems correct to me. The standard approach is to show a circular progress indicator ```Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())``` with the FutureBuilder, like [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

Comment: Also, null and 0 are the same state from UI point of view. You could show a picture with "Your list is empty" type of message, like recommended by Material Design

Comment: Hi @Alessio, thanks for the interest to help. You're right but what I am trying to achieve here is when there are no available items to show on a list, I'll show a Call to Action button inviting the user to create an object. But whenever the app restarts, it always show my Call to Action button briefly even if the user has already created objects before. This is more a system design consultation with Flutter I guess? :) btw, I'm using Provider for my list object and in manipulating it

Comment: @AverageCoder I see, and I think my answer / approach is still valid. Enter the page with a FutureBuilder<String>, let your Future<String> to return "I am ready" once done (this could set either an empty list or a valid list). You will show a spinner until snapshot.hasData branch is entered. Once there, you check for list to be empty or not. If empty, you'll show the call to action button, otherwise the list. I think this is what you're looking for. Tweak it at your will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your comment, I think something like this will do:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Future<List<Item>> _items;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // here maybe you won't use the server side, but some local storage
    _items = Web.fetchItems();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Item>>(
      future: _items,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          if (_items.isEmpty) {
            return _MyCallToActionButtonLayout();
          }
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('My title'),
            ),
            body: buildListView(snapshot.data)),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("${snapshot.error}");
        } else {
          return Scaffold(body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I actually am reconsidering my design now with the remarks that you've provided. Cheers!